# Jhipster 4.13 - Skip authentication from Jhipster

Tags: security, authentication, jhipster, skip

I have generated a v4.13 jhipster application and included as maven module in my "Big Application". Everything is working.

Now I would like to authenticate in JHipster with a token which the "Big Application provides". 
Is it possible to do that ? Is it possible/necessary to skip the auth part of Jhipster in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Before generation no, the only way is to manually edit SecurityConfiguration. Tnere could be alternatives depending on which authentication type uses Big Application.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for your answer. Do I need to overwrite all the methods on this class ?

Comment: It depends on many things I don't know about your "Big Application". The only advice I can give you is to know well Spring Security before starting.